# SQLite Update query is not working in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am having a table called Demo in SQLite with Phonegap. I've inserted few values in it. Now I want to update one record.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);

db.transaction(updatemonthSaveingDB, errorCB);

function updatemonthSaveingDB(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql("UPDATE DEMO SET data = " + submitval + " WHERE id = " + 8, [], updateCB, errorCB);
}

function errorCB(err) 
{
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
```

Now when I throw this query, it shows **Error processing SQL: 0 ** alert.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the way of passing variable inside a sqlite query is incorrect
In this function

```
function updatemonthSaveingDB(tx) 
{
tx.executeSql("UPDATE DEMO SET data = " + submitval + " WHERE id = " + 8, [],   updateCB, errorCB);
 }
```

sqlite consider "UPDATE DEMO SET data = "  as a query because you have used  " incorrectly.
The correct way is:

```
      function updatemonthSaveingDB(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql("UPDATE DEMO SET data ='" +submitval+"' WHERE id = '"+8+"' ;", [],   updateCB, errorCB);
}
```

Comment: Why should it work? Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain.

Comment: Why not using parameterized query?

tx.executeSql("UPDATE DEMO SET data =? WHERE id = ?" , [submitval, 8],   updateCB, errorCB);

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is happening is that your transaction is actually successful. If you go and look at this table of SQLite Error Codes (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) you'll see that an error message of "0" reads as "/* Successful result */".

If "updateCB" is not actually a function (you don't define it here) is it possible that errorCB is being read as your success callback and being called as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Give quote `''` beetween each column value.

I also remove `[], updateCB, errorCB);`. it wouldn't work if you not declare `updateCB` and `errorCB` function.

I update the code. work for me.

```
function updatemonthSaveingDB(tx) 
{
   tx.executeSql("UPDATE DEMO SET data='" + submitval + "' WHERE id='8'");
}
```